# remove duplicate from React project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using `React` as a front-end library for my rails project, I have been through an issue which is showing the errors for the user, I'm using Ajax to send request but I found my self duplicating error call back function if the server-side returns errors in every request inside every `React.Component` something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: METHOD,
    data: { 
       //data 
    },
    success: function () {
      //calling some function
    }.bind(this),
    error(error) {

      // begin
      server_errors = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
      array_of_keys_of_errors = Object.keys(server_errors);
      for( i = 0 ; i < array_of_keys_of_errors.length; i++){
        nested_keys = Object.keys(server_errors[array_of_keys_of_errors[i]]);
        for( j = 0 ; j < nested_keys.length; j++){
          array_of_errors = server_errors[array_of_keys_of_errors[i]][nested_keys[j]];
          for( k = 0 ; k < array_of_errors.length; k++){
            bootbox.alert({
              message: nested_keys[j] + ' ' + array_of_errors[k],
              closeButton: false,
            });
          }
        }
      }
      // end
    },
  });
```

Is there an efficient way to keep my code away from redundancy, I was thinking about a shared file contains shared functions and include it inside each React.Component but I didn't find something similar to this.

Comment: Isn't this a server-side issue? Try adding `distinct` keyword to your SQL query.

Comment: No,  i'm duplicating the code that is response for showing errors to the user in every request that I make, this is my problem.

Comment: Can you share error function with us

Comment: Edited, that block of code between `begin` and `end` comments what I'm duplicating in every Ajax request which annoying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function to handle your errors:

```
function handleErrors(errors) {
  const server_errors = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
  const array_of_keys_of_errors = Object.keys(server_errors);
  for( i = 0 ; i < array_of_keys_of_errors.length; i++){
    nested_keys = Object.keys(server_errors[array_of_keys_of_errors[i]]);
    for( j = 0 ; j < nested_keys.length; j++){
      array_of_errors = server_errors[array_of_keys_of_errors[i]][nested_keys[j]];
      for( k = 0 ; k < array_of_errors.length; k++){
        bootbox.alert({
          message: nested_keys[j] + ' ' + array_of_errors[k],
          closeButton: false,
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And share that function across your files.

You would use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: URL,
  type: METHOD,
  data: { 
     //data 
  },
  success: function () {
    //calling some function
  }.bind(this),
  handleErrors
})
```

Comment: I was trying to do this at first but I was doing it incorrectly with my rails project, I create that function in separated file under `app/assets/javascript` with name `shared_functions.js` and it worked, Thanks.